# Problem while implement location listener in android appwidget

Tags: android, gps, android-widget, listener

I am working on a Widget which will get the Current GPS location and pass this value to remote PHP page to get the Information and display it in the Widget. This is what I am trying to do.

I am facing problem while implementing Location Listener for appWidget. It is not updating with the Current Location and It is showing the initial widget i.e "Loading Widget"(Here I put this text)

**Can we implement Location Listener for AppWidgetProvider?**
  Or
  **Can you suggest me the possible solution for getting GPS location in App Widget?**

I placed all necessary permissions in Manifest file.
Here is my code snippet:

```
public class test extends AppWidgetProvider {
static LocationManager locMan;
static Location curLocation;
static Boolean locationChanged;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // To prevent any ANR timeouts, we perform the update in a service
    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
}

public static class UpdateService extends Service {
    // GPS Listener Class
    LocationListener gpsListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Log.w("GPS", "Started");
            if (curLocation == null) {
                curLocation = location;
                locationChanged = true;
            }

            if (curLocation.getLatitude() == location.getLatitude() && curLocation.getLongitude() == location.getLongitude())
                locationChanged = false;
            else
                locationChanged = true;

            curLocation = location;

            if (locationChanged) 
                locMan.removeUpdates(gpsListener);

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Log.w("GPS", "Location changed", null);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            if (status == 0)// UnAvailable
            {

            } else if (status == 1)// Trying to Connect
            {

            } else if (status == 2) {// Available

            }
        }

    };

    // In service start method, I am registering for GPS Updates
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,20000, 1, gpsListener);
        } else {
            this.startActivity(new Intent("android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS"));
        }

        if (curLocation != null) {
            double lat = curLocation.getLatitude();
            double lng = curLocation.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Lat : " + String.valueOf(lat) + "\n Long : "+ String.valueOf(lng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        // Build the widget update for today
        RemoteViews updateViews = buildUpdate(this);

        // Push update for this widget to the home screen
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this,InKakinadaWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);

    }

    public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {
        // Here I am updating the remoteview
        return updateViews;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't need to bind to this service
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Thanks in Advance...

With Regards,
Raghavendra K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you having this problem in the emulator or on a device?  If on the emulator, make sure you use DDMS to set a GPS location.  But the easiest thing to do might be to run your code on a device to see if you get GPS updates that way.

Comment: Hi Mike,
     I tested in my HTC Hero. But no luck. Is there any wrong with my code? 
or can you suggest me any other way to get gps location in Widget?

Thanks for your quick respnose...

Comment: I'd love to help but I'm not very familiar with widgets.  One thing I forgot to mention is to make sure you walk around outside with your device -- I've struggled with code in the past, only to realize that the device couldn't get a GPS fix indoors and thus wasn't sending me GPS updates at all.

Answer (score 8):

The problem I see is that you are trying to check curLocation in onStart() right after calling requestLocationUpdates(). LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() is asynchronous, meaning your LocationListener will not get called back until after onStart() has returned. Have your LocationListener update the UI after it receives the location, don't try and do it in onStart.

Comment: Hi Bryan,
        You are right. I faced the problem with the Time Intervals which I have given to the AppWidget(20 sec) and the Location Listener(2 sec). Then both are not synchronized with each other. I set the Time Interval for AppWidget to 1 minute and for Location Listener to 20 seconds. Now it is working fine...

     Thank you very much for your guidance...

Comment: Happy to help. If you have a minute, perhaps mark this answer as the correct one.