# How to listen for location updates from multiple providers?

Tags: android, locationlistener

In this code I request location updates from GPS

```
locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,20000, 1, gpsListener);
```

But how can I make sure it listens for Wifi or Cell ID updates too?

Comment: look at this question and answeir - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595522/use-gps-and-network-provider-at-the-same-time-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call `requestLocationUpdates()`, with distinct `LocationListener` objects, for the other providers.

Comment: Thanks. There is a solution linked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801866/problem-while-implement-location-listener-in-android-appwidget

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you can share the same listener. Just user Location.getProvider() in the listener to find out which provider generated the update.