# How to change automatically from GPS_PROVIDER to NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, android-location

Is there any Code I can use, so that I do not have to implement it on my own to change automatically from `GPS_PROVIDER` to `NETWORK_PROVIDER`?

actually I use this code:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

But I want to do the following:
Try to use GPS, as long as it is not available use the `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. But when GPS get available switch to it. When the GPS is lost switch back to the `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the new fused location provider in Google Play Services. It was presented at the Google IO 2013.

It removes the hassle of selecting a certain LocationProvider, provides better results and much more.

For an overview have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) or watch the [Video](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325337477). For fused location provider  code example tune in at 16:00.

Answer (score 2):

```
Location loc =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);    
    if(loc == null)
    {
        loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(loc != null)
        {
            //do stuff on network provider
        }

    } else {
        // do stuff on gps provider
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest a better option, try use a Criteria to select the best Provider. It will switch automatically switch for the best provider.

```
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

Get a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) for more details.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

use locationmanager.getProviders as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595522/use-gps-and-network-provider-at-the-same-time-in-android).
this way each time your location listener will be entered, you'll be able to pick your location from available providers.