# MyLocationOverlay problem

Tags: android

```
private void initMyLocation() {
        myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, myMap);
        myLocOverlay.enableCompass();
        myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        myMap.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay);
        if (myLocOverlay == null)
    { 
        assignFirstLoc();

    }


if (myLocOverlay != null)
            {
                Log.e("error","1");
                p = new GeoPoint((int) (myLocOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6()), (int) (myLocOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6()));
                mc = myMap.getController();
                mc.animateTo(p);
                mc.setCenter(p); 

            }
```

I saw "error 1" message in the logcat but after that I took an null pointer exception I dont know why, I believe I check myLocOverlay is null or not with "if" block.. Any suggesstions?

Edit:

This is my assignedGFirstLoc method that assigned the firtst values:

```
private void assignFirstLoc()
    {
        final String coordinates[] = {"41.00527", "28.97696"};
        double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng2 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
        p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat2 * 1E6), (int) (lng2 * 1E6));
        myMap.getController().setZoom(16);
        myMap.getController().animateTo(p);
        myMap.getController().setCenter(p);

    }
```

Comment: try to check value of getMyLocation()

Comment: how? I think laptop cant take any location because of gps issue.

Comment: with toast message I took "null" value in cellphone.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why do you null-check `MyLocationOverlay`? It clearly can never be null when you check it as you have instantiated it so it can never be null down there.

Comment: I really dont know if you want I can send my project. I just want to get my location and try to centered of my screen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`MyLocationOverlay` can only be used to show a location coming from sensors.
You cannot set it.
You got a NullPointer because `MyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation()` returns null. Sensors didn't have the time to catch the geolocation yet.

If you want to show the location when the sensor got the data you can do this:

```
mMyLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() { public void run() {
        mapView.getController().animateTo(mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
}});
```

If you want to display an item in an arbitray location (with latitude and longitude values) you need to  implement your own version of `ItemizedOverlay`
You can find an exemple in the SDK documentation: [Google Map View tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html), Part2 AddingOverlayItem

If you just want to show an arbitrary location on the map, you don't need an overlay. just call your function and it will work:

```
private void initMyLocation() {
    assignFirstLoc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not passing any coordinates into GeoPoint. Unless it is somewhere else in your code. Something like this works

```
String coordinates[] = {"41.146064", "-80.642861"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
```

Comment: Yea, your way works but assume that I'm somewhere else that I dont know the exact coordinates so I have to use location.getLatitude() or myLocOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6() methods but these methods give an error

Comment: You have to have some means of determining your geo location as in using a GPS location on an android device

Comment: your nullpointer is due to the absence of geopoint data. MyLocationOverlay implements android.hardware.SensorListener and android.location.LocationListener. So somewhere you will have to get your geocoded location from your device. I am using overlays, but my geopoint data comes from a database. I do however know that LocationListener should work for you. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801866/problem-while-implement-location-listener-in-android-appwidget

Comment: I added a my assignFirstLoc method. as you understand I assigned a spesific data to geopoint. Then onCreate method compiles again I've a geopoint value and I think myLocOverlay is not null but I added a toast messsage to my initMyLocation method and it returns "null" :S